# Typing getter of a property in a Typescript union

Tags: typescript, types

I have theses Typescript types :

```
type A = {
  a: string
}

type B = {
  b: number,
}

type C = number;

type U = A | B | C;
```

I'm trying to write the function that, given a property of one of `U` types, return the property value or `undefined`.

In Javascript, it would be something like that:

```
function getProp(prop: P) {
  return (thing) => {
    if (typeof thing === 'object' && prop in thing) {
      return thing[prop]
    }

    return undefined;
  }  
}
```

Example:

```
const u: U = ...;

const a: string | undefined = getProp('a')(u);
```

I've tried this:

```
type KeysOfUnion<T> = T extends any ? keyof T : never; // because `keyof U` return `never`

function getProp<P extends KeysOfUnion<U>>(prop: P) {
    return (thing: U): U[P] => { // error: `Type 'P' cannot be used to index type 'U'.`
        if (typeof thing === 'object' && prop in thing) {
          return thing[prop]; // error: Type 'P' cannot be used to index type 'A | B'
        }

        return undefined; // error: Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'U[P]'.
    }
}

const a: string | undefined = getProp('a')(u);
```

But this is not valid. I think I have to find an alternative for `U[P]` if I want to type this strange function properly but I don't see what. Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the caller's side of view, you probably want `getProp()` to return a function which returns `IdxUnion<U, P>`, where `IdxUnion` is defined like this:

```
type IdxUnion<T, K extends PropertyKey> =
  T extends any ? K extends keyof T ? T[K] : undefined : never;
```

This will do the lookup for each member of a union `T` and return either `T[K]` or `undefined` depending on whether or not `K` is a key of that member of `T`.  This should fix things from the call side, mostly:

```
const a = getProp('a')(u); // string | undefined
```

I say "mostly" because the function implementation doesn't quite do what you're saying it will do given the signature: if `u` is a `number` and not an object, you are always returning `undefined` at runtime, but `number` has keys such as `toFixed`, so you'd expect `getProp('toFixed')(123)` to be a function.  This is mostly not a problem for your particular `U`, since `A` and `B` will give you the `undefined` that actually comes out, but it's weird.  So be careful:

```
const hmm = getProp('toFixed')(123);
// ((fractionDigits?: number | undefined) => string) | undefined
```

---

Inside the implemementation of `getProp()`, things are tougher.  The compiler generally has a hard time evaluating the type safety of operations that occur on unspecified generic types, especially conditional types.  Your best bet here is probably to use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler that you know what you're doing:

```
if (typeof thing === "object" && prop in thing) {
  return thing[prop as keyof typeof thing]; // assert
}
return undefined as IdxUnion<U, P>; // assert
```

---

Anyway, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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)

Comment: Thanks @jcalz for your detailed answer and for pointing out I was missing some keys like `toFixed` in my implementation. Completely forgot about them!